What can prevent No routes found for "//"
So I'm having trouble pinpointing a problem. I was noticing in error logs that '//' was not found.
So I'm trying to understand why that is, and if there's a way to catch this and redirect before symfony tries to process it using subscribers.
Problem: user visits http://example.com//
I need to redirect it from // to http://example.com
I tried creating a subscriber to see if i could get path information and I got no output for that route.
class InvalidUrlRedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() : array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => ['onKernelController', 10],
        ];
    }

    // public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) return;

        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo());
        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getUri());
        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getBaseUrl());
        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getBasePath());
        echo 'hi';
    }
}

I've also tried the version wher eit's just the RequestEvent, and still nothing.
Edit: I'm using a basic nginx server.

First check what cause the invalid path //. If you cannot modify id, try to rewrite it in the nginx. The last resolve it to your php, add a router for it and redirect it.

Please [edit] into your question (e.g. at the end) which web server you're using (and the version), and same for PHP and Symfony. And the PHP SAPI can also be of interest if you know the name by chance.

@LF-DevJourney yeah I was trying to figure this out as well, my other project's // works fine and gets redirected properly automatically, symfony understands that's an invalid path. So I'm guessing there's a route configuration issue elsewhere because I had a feeling I was solving a problem that shouldn't be a problem.


Problem: user visits http://example.com//
I need to redirect it from // to http://example.com

Yes, and please allow me to add a little detail upfront: You want the redirect to go to http://example.com/; that is including a single slash. This is only important as an URL needs to have this path separator after the host[:port] part.
I assume in good faith you already meant this, but it might be helpful to get everyone on the same page when answering the question.
Let's see what we have so far:
    http://example.com//  -->  http://example.com/

In my understanding this operation, we may call it "redirect" or just "URL path normalization", should not be the obligation of the Symfony application or any of the PHP scripts it makes use of.
Instead, whenever a request hits the application, the path should already be normalized.
Now which component is responsible for that? While the client may use the http://example.com// URL with the two slashes, it is the web server that receives it next.
This is the place I'd suggest taking care of it, the web server. Consult your web server documentation and look for the configuration setting to normalize paths in HTTP requests. Often they already have (as well as for normalizing other parts of the URL next to the path, like the query parameters).
In case you already know which web server you're using, please share it by editing your question; then ping me in a comment below so that it could be purposefully addressed in the context of a Symfony application and other PHP scripts.

I understand what redirection is and my problem is I can't actually get the path information using a subscriber lol. I obviously know the next step is to redirect, but the subscriber actually has to catch the request information and in my case it does not.
On paper symfony should already handle //, but my flex application is not. It thinks for whatever reason that this route needs to be registered and I'm unsure why the empty "space/" would need to be registered. a single forward slash / already gets handled by symfony, but a double forward // thinks it's supposed to be a registered route

I think what @hakre is suggesting is to fix this in the web server, not in symfony.
